# Check if executable command exists using ant

Tags: ant

Is it possible to check if a command exists as part of an ant task. For example, I want to ensure the "yasm" command is present as part of the ant task. Is this possible? If so, can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of to do this is by using the `available` task combined with an `if` in a subsequent target. If you take a look at that [task page](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/available.html) you will see that you can check to see if something exists then set a property. For example:

```
<available file="/path/to/my/file" type="file" property="file.present"/>
```

Then in the [target](http://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html) you would say something like `<target name='foo' if='file.present'>`

That doesn't check for executable permissions but it will get much closer. If a task exists to check for the executable permission specifically you would still probably combine it with the `if` in the target.

---

Original answer

It is better to use the ant copy task instead of trying to execute `cp` yourself. This keeps its platform independent.

```
<copy todir"/some/target">
   <fileset dir="/some/src"/>
</copy>
```

More usage on the [Ant documentation for the copy task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html).

Comment: "cp" was just a random command I picked out as an example, sorry for the confusion. This answer would  be correct if I was asking because I intended to copy files with that command.

Comment: That is quite an example! Let me think.

Answer (score 20):

The following idiom can be used to find an executable somewhere in the environment's PATH.

```
  <property environment="env" /> 
  <available file="commandname"  
             filepath="${env.PATH}"  
             property="commandname.present"/>
```